# Can't find assets publicly via URL

Tags: assets, craft3

Basically, I have an asset volume called Images, with

base URL: /photos/
file system path: ~media/images

Then I go to upload the asset and I try to view it, it gives me a 404 "Template not Found"

mydomain.com/photos/image.jpg

Comment: `~media/images` is going to point the user's home directory on *nix operating systems.  Maybe you meant to use a relative path? i.e. `media/images` or `./media/images`?

Comment: @BradBell thanks for your response.

The files are there (in the right location).  I want to move them to another location eventually, but for now I just wanted to test and see if I could even access the assets publicly via URL.

It shouldn't be giving a template error if it's correctly routing the URL to the file, right?

Comment: @BradBell I updated it to be a relative path and it is still giving me a templating error.